# Including a 'set' inside of a 'struct'

Tags: c++, callback, struct, set

I'm trying to include a set, inside a struct, but I don't know how to pass the callback compare function to the set constructor when doing this.

This is a basic example of what I've tried:

```
struct pointT { 
    int x; 
    int y; 
};

struct pathT{
    Stack<pointT> pointsInPath;
    Set<pointT> pointsIncluded; // need callback here?
};

// Tried this.
//struct pathT{
    //Stack<pointT> pointsInPath;
    //Set<pointT> pointsIncluded(ComparePoints); //doesn't work of course
//};


//Callback function to compare set of points.
int ComparePoints(pointT firstPoint, pointT secondPoint){

    if (firstPoint.x == secondPoint.x && firstPoint.y == secondPoint.y) return 0;
    if (firstPoint.x < secondPoint.x) return -1;
    else return 1;
}


int main() {

    Set<pointT> setOfPoints(ComparePoints); // this works fine
    //pathT allPaths; // not sure how to assign call back function here to a set inside a struct

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct in c++ is automatically a class.

therefore you can provide a constructor

```
struct pathT {
    public:
    pathT();

    private:
    Stack<pointT> pointsInPath;
    Set<pointT> pointsIncluded; 
};

pathT::pathT()
: pointsIncluded(ComparePoints)
{

}
```

regards

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom default constructor:

```
struct pathT{
    Stack<pointT> pointsInPath;
    Set<pointT> pointsIncluded; // need callback here?

    pathT() : pointsIncluded(ComparePoints) { }
};
```

While you're at it, move the comparator into a struct (which can be inlined, unlike a function pointer), and define it as a `<` operator, which is what `set` expects:

```
struct ComparePoints {
    bool operator()(const pointT& a, const pointT& b){
        return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y);
    }
};

struct pathT {
    ...
    pathT() : pointsIncluded(ComparePoints()) { }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that.  Can you provide a short example?

Comment: @joeh100: I've edited my answer a couple of times, but every version has offered code to match the explanation. I'm not sure what else you need.

Comment: I think I got confused between edits.  Also shouldn't the first example you provided use the same name for pointsIncluded instead of setOfPoints?